# Where can I download the bootstrap.js of bootswatch?

Tags: bootswatch

I can't find the `bootstrap.js` and `jquery` of https://bootswatch.com/ theme I am using. If I press the download, it only shows the `css` and no `js`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Javascript is already written and is part of bootstrap, you just need to import it. A line like this should do the trick for you, assuming you have that file in the bootstrap folder.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/bootstrap.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

To download jQuery and also include that in the page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

[You can download jQuery here.](http://jquery.com/)